# snowflake - How to use a file format to decode a csv column?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I've got some data in a string column that is in a strange csv format. I can write a file format that correctly interprets it. How do I use my file format against data that has already been imported?

```
create table test_table
(
    my_csv_column string
)
```

How do I split/flatten this column with:

```
create or replace file format my_csv_file_format
type = 'CSV'
RECORD_DELIMITER = '0x0A'
field_delimiter = ' '
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
VALIDATE_UTF8 = FALSE
```

Please assume that I cannot use split, as I want to use the rich functionality of the file format (optional escape characters, date recognition etc.).

What I'm trying to achieve is something like the below (but I cannot find how to do it)

```
copy into destination_Table 
from 
(select

s.$1 
,s.$2 
,s.$3 
,s.$4 
from test_table s
file_format = (column_name ='my_csv_column' , format_name = 'my_csv_file_format'))
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to achieve, please provide a more concrete example.

Comment: @MarcinZukowski I've re-written the question, I hope the examples help

Comment: Interesting. I don't think Snowflake today supports using a file format on  strings. That would be an interesting functionality! However, since we don't have it, you can COPY a table into a stage using a simple textual output, and then use the file format to scan the generated files.